# My css flexbox is not working on any browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning css these days. I am designing a navbar by using css flexbox. Here is my html and css code, but they are not working on my browser.
Can anybody find any problem?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Website Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/originals/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="MyOnlineMeal.com">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#services-container">Services</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#client-section">Our Clients</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: define *not working*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display: flex property only applies to the **direct children elements** within the flex container. I'm guessing that you want the list items to also be "flexed" so in order to do that - you need to apply display flex to the ul as well as the nav.

In other words - the nav bar applies display flex to ONLY the div containing the image image and the ul. In order to align and space out the list items - the ul needs to also be a flex container. I am using space-around to space out the list items - but obviously you might need to alter the styling to suit your needs.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
/* Navigation Bar */
#navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    top: 0px;
}


#navbar ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    top: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 32px
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
   <div id="logo">
       <img src="logo.png" alt="MyOnlineMeal.com">
    </div>
    <ul>
       <li class="item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#services-container">Services</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#client-section">Our Clients</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, I suppose you need all items in the navbar evenly distributed on a horizontal line on top of the page. If that is what you need, a few indications:

- The main problem is that `display: flex` will distribute only the immediate children of the box with that property. In your case it means that your flex items are the logo `div` and the `ul` as a whole, and it will not distribute the items inside the `ul`. To achieve the latter effect, you would also need to set the `ul` display to flex.
- You are using the `align-items` property to configure flex items alignment, but this property aligns items in the direction **opposite** to the flex direction. As your flex direction is row, `align-items: center` aligns them in center **vertically**, from top to bottom. You won't notice its effects here because your container by default has the same height as its content, so items can't be assigned different vertical positions. But if you specify a larger height for your flex container, you will notice that all flex items will appear in the middle of the flex container's height; that could be useful in the outer flex container to align the ul items in the middle of the logo's height.
- You should try the property `justify-content` to align your flex items in the **same direction** of your flex container, in this case horizontally. Try checking different values for this property, like `space-around` or `space-evenly` to achieve the distribution you need.
- The `top` property is not needed here, unless you use it with a positioned element. You need to use it together with some value for the `position` property.

Comment: Thank you Sir... I am learning.... So much thanks for these beautiful and strong words.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS flexbox handles the row and column alignment of direct children elements to the parent in which flexbox has been applied. For Example, In your code:

- `<nav id="navbar">` is the parent which contains direct children elements,  `<div id="logo">` and  `<ul>`, anything inside   `<div id="logo">` and  `<ul>` are not the direct children to `<nav id="navbar">`. So, if you observe the `<div>` containing logo and the `<ul>` containing list of links are aligned horizontally beside each other due to `#navbar ul{ display: flex;}`
- In order to make your list of links appear beside each other horizontally much alike your logo and list, you will need to give `<ul>` element display flex because `<ul>` acts as the direct parent element to `<li>` elements ; and since default value of flex-direction is row you may or may not set the value for it, as you like.
  Hope this helps clarifying your concepts. Keep Learning!

```css
#navbar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#navbar > ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#navbar > ul > li{
  margin-right: 0.875rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
   <div id="logo">
       <img src="logo.png" alt="MyOnlineMeal.com">
    </div>
    <ul>
       <li class="item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#services-container">Services</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#client-section">Our Clients</a></li>
       <li class="item"><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```